# How do I sum the values in multiple cells based on criteria in multiple rows?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to pull the sum of multiple values from one Excel sheet into another based on criteria in a column.  Vlookup doesn't work because it only pulls the first value, rather than multiple.

I want the sum of the values in column E (Sheet2) where Column C (Sheet2) equals Column A in Sheet 1

[image: Sheet2: I want the sum of the values in column E (Sheet2) where Column C (Sheet2) equals Column A in Sheet 1]

In B2, I want the sum of all values from Sheet2 where Column A equals 7 A.M.

[image: Sheet1: In B2, I want the sum of all values from Sheet2 where Column A equals 7 A.M.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want SUMIFS()

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!E:E,Sheet2!C:C,A2)
```